# How can i recursively calculate the depth of a tree structure in Clojure?

Tags: recursion, clojure, tree

So i've got a very basic understanding of Clojure and would like to calculate the depth of a tree defined using a vector containing vectors itself. For instance, [1 [2] [3 [4] ]] would represent a tree where 1 is the root while [2] is a child to 1 and [3 [4]] a subtree.

```
(defn height[tree]
(if(empty? tree)
    (1); Base case
    (inc (apply max (map  height (next tree))))); Calculate the height for every subtree and return maximum
)
```

I was thinking that this method would work, as it's supposed to recursively calculate the depth of every subtree to return the maximum value. However, i get an Illegal argument exception when I try to run this method.

Comment: Is this a binary tree?

Stupid question: wouldn't it be sufficient to count +1 for every opening bracket and -1 for every closing? Taking the max value would result in having the depth :)

Comment: @J.Dow NO. The result  is always 0, since the brackets are balanced.

Comment: Yep, i meant taking the max value. For the given example:
[1 [2] [3 [4] ]] -> +1 (1) + 1(2) -1(1) + 1(2) + 1(3) -1(2) -1(1) -1(1) -> 3 
No recursion needed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `(1)` is wrong. It tries to execute `1` as a function.
- You need to be able to cope with leaves in the tree, which are not
  vectors.
- The `next` call is wrong - leave it out.

Try

```
(defn height [tree]
  (if (vector? tree)
   (if (empty? tree)
     1
     (inc (apply max (map height tree))))
    0))
```

For example,

```
(height [1 [2] [3 [4] ]]) ; 3
```

A slightly simpler version is

```
(defn height [tree]
  (if (vector? tree)
    (inc (apply max 0 (map height tree)))
    0))
```

By supplying an initial/default argument `0` to the `max`, we deal with an empty collection without a condition.

Comment: but notice, that it is not tail recursive: `(height (nth (iterate (partial vector 1) []) 250))` => StackOverflowError   clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:130) , so even 250 levels high tree causes stackoverflow

Comment: @leetwinsk My stack busts somewhere above 1000, but your principle is valid.

Comment: wow, something's wrong with my repl than ) . Thousand would probably be enough for the most cases, the problem is that it is device-specific and indeterministic

Comment: @leetwinski No. Just different settings.

Answer (score 6):

tail recursive variant with zippers:

```
(require '[clojure.zip :as z])

(defn height-2 [tree]
  (loop [curr (z/zipper coll? seq nil tree) h 0]
    (if (z/end? curr) h
        (recur (z/next curr)
               (if (z/branch? curr) h
                   (-> curr z/path count (max h)))))))
```

in repl:

```
user> (height-2 [1 [2] [3 [4] ]])
3
user> (height-2 (nth (iterate (partial vector 1) []) 1000))
1000
user> (height-2 (nth (iterate (partial vector 1) []) 100000))
100000
```

Comment: Though the question asks for a recursive solution, this is more robust, and helpful to those of us grappling with zippers.

Comment: @Thumbnail , yours is obviously more relevant to the op's question, since he was trying to do exactly what you did there. Mine is just an addition.

Comment: I think this is *slightly* different from OP's intentions, which give an empty tree height 1. You can get this by replacing `seq` with `identity` in the `zipper` construction.